# Regex to match two groups of strings within brackets

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I have a block of text that includes the following:

```
race={ heat1={ names={ ALEX DAN PETER } } heat2={ names={ RYAN DYLAN } } }
```

How would I build a regex to get all of the heat1 names into group 1, and all of the heat2 names into group 2? I can't find a one-for-one question that's already been asked, and the closest I'm able to get is:

```
(?:names={)( [A-z]+ )
```

Which returns ALEX and RYAN in the same group.

Comment: Use `names={([A-Z ]+)` and then split stripped matches with whitespace. See [`[x.strip().split() for x in re.findall(r"names={([A-Z ]+)", s)]`](https://ideone.com/iqmDPa).

Answer (score 2):

With `re.findall()` function:

```
import re

s = 'race={ heat1={ names={ ALEX DAN PETER } } heat2={ names={ RYAN DYLAN } } }'
result = re.findall(r'heat[12]=\{ names=\{ ([^}]+[^}\s])', s)

print(result)
```

The output:

```
['ALEX DAN PETER', 'RYAN DYLAN']
```